train yolo weights to recognize one additional image?
I have a a YOLO model that I am training to make it able to recognize a new object with a new class defined in the new data to use for the training.
Full code for the training with the new data is as follows:
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8/weights/yolov8n.pt')
results = model(source='./weirdobject.jpg', conf=0.25, save_txt=None)[0]
print(results)

annotated_frame = results.plot()   

import cv2



import supervision as sv

sv.plot_image(annotated_frame)

#use roboflow to download the data annotated with the new image (the dataset contains 1 annotated image)
from roboflow import Roboflow

rf = Roboflow(api_key="idofproject")
print(rf.workspace().projects())
project = rf.workspace("id1").project("id2")
version = project.version(4)
#download the data from roboflow to train the model with
dataset = version.download(model_format="yolov8", location="./datasets")

#train the model with the data containing the added annotated image
results = model.train(data="roboflow_ml_image_detection/datasets/data.yaml", epochs=5)

results = model.val()
#yield the new predictions that should include the new image detection with the right label
results = model(source='./weirdobject.jpg', conf=0.25, save_txt=None)[0]
# this results is wrong as if the model wasn't trained with the new data containing the new image
print(results)

The dataset containing one image is downloaded into the python project and has the following structure:

The data.yaml file is the following:
names:
- small_ball
nc: 1
roboflow:
  license: CC BY 4.0
  project: nao-s07zd
  url: https://universe.roboflow.com/id1/id2/dataset/4
  version: 4
  workspace: id2
#test: ../test/images
train: ./train/images
val: ./valid/images

The second results are the same as prior the training, why?
